# Как пройти проверку qr кода в реальном времени, не сканируя его, а отправляя заранее готовую картинку, на сайте?

Tags: python, qr

https://attendance-app.mirea.ru/selfapprove
Есть сайт, после авторизации появляется окно для сканирования qr кода.
Хочется узнать, каким образом возможно отправить в запросе заранее готовый qr код, с помощью кода на python, не сканируя его в реальном времени.
Догадываюсь, что это возможно осуществить, отправив post запрос с картинкой (кодом). Либо же иным путем сделать эмуляцию камеры которая как бы "направлена" на эту заготовленную картинку.
Каким образом это разумнее сделать и какие инструменты использовать?
Всем заранее спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то можно сделать так:

**· Установить и запустить OBS** *(https://obsproject.com/ru)*

**· Нажать на + во вкладке "Источники"**

**· Выбрать "Изображение"**

**· Нажать "Обзор" и выбрать изображение QR-кода**

**· Нажать "Ок"**

**· И нажать "Запуск виртуальной камеры"**

**· И на сайте выбрать камеру OBS**

К сожалению, не на python, но помог чем мог.

Comment: спасибо за ответ!! огромное спасибо! но тут делема не в том. нужно как бы отправить данные qr-а сайту когда он их запрашиваеш НЕ показывая в камеру сам qr, но вновьвновь и вновь спасибо!